# BackboneJS delete item from a Model array

Tags: backbone.js

I have this collection:

```
var items = new bb.Collections.QuotesCollection([
    {id: 1, name: "item 1", units: []},
    {id: 2, name: "item 2", units: []},
    {id: 3, name: "item 3", units: []}
]);
```

And then I output the array "units" like so:

```
if(this.model.get('units').length){
        $(this.el).append('<strong>Units</strong>');
        $(this.el).append('<ul>');
        for(x in this.model.get('units')){
            $(this.el).append('<li class="unit">' + this.model.get('units')[x] + '</li>');
        }
        $(this.el).append('</ul>');
    }
```

The code above is only POC stuff, so no formal templating as yet.

```
events: {
    "keypress #addUnit" : "addUnit",
    "dblclick .unit" : "deleteUnit"
},

deleteUnit: function(){
    this.render(); // what do I put here!?
}
```

What approach do I take to delete an item (the clicked one) from the "units" array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the quick and dirty method:

Assuming the Array's order is not changed through any other medium, you could do

```
deleteUnit: function() {
  // get the index of the li you are clicking
  var index = $('.unit').index(this);
  this.model.get('units').splice(index, 1);
  this.render();
}
```

This way you have to remember to empty your view element  before every render

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.empty();
  ...
  // business as usual
}
```

Comment: As far as you can see, are there any drawbacks to your "quick and dirty" method? Would I be better following the answer below from @mrappleton?

Comment: Well, the drawbacks are that you have to remember to keep the ui up to date all the time. So every sort, addition and deletion operation should come with a render. Otherwise I see no drawbacks, some purists might have a problem with extracting the index from the DOM. mrappleton's solution doesn't really answer your problem, because your units are not models

Comment: also I see no point making a model out of each unit the way this is portrayed, although the situation changes if each unit is for example a reference to a model (like unit id, etc)

Comment: A downside of this approach is that modifying an array attribute in-place won't trigger a `"change"` event. You'd have to trigger the change events by hand (ick) or pull the array out, make a copy, splice the copy, and then `set` the new array; doing that outside the model is more ick but adding a `remove_unit` method to the model  that does all that would be fairly clean.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably want to have a view object for each model, so you'd have a collection view which owns the `<ul>` and looks like this:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    var html = '<ul></ul>'; // make your html here (usually with templates)
    this.$el.append(html);        
    this.collection.each(_.bind(this.initChild, this));
    return this; // so we can chain calls if we want to.
  }
  initChild: function(model) {
    var child = new ChildView({ model: model });
    // this.$() is scoped to the view's el property
    this.$('ul').append(child.render().el);
  }
});
```

You'd then set up the child views something like this:

```
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: { 'click .delete', 'deleteModel' },
  render: function() {
    var html = '';// make your html here (usually with templates)
    this.$el.append(html);
    return this;
  },
  deleteModel: function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    // Removes form the collection and sends an xhr DELETE
    this.model.destroy(); 
    this.$el.remove();
  }
});
```

The call to Model#destroy will take care of removing it from the collection and sending a DELETE to the server (assuming you have a URL set up in your collection/model).

Comment: So, to clarify, I would create a new model and a new view for each "units" array item? Would I also need a collection as well? (n00b concepts)

Comment: this answer mistakenly assumes that the units are models which are stored in a collection

Comment: Ah good point, units are just a dumb array on the model aren't they. In that case I would either refactor them to be a proper Collection, or go with something like 'quick & dirty' below. Which depends on how much more you want to do with units I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you need to delete item from model

`Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      alert("Welcome to this world");
    }
});
var person = new Person({ name: "Thomas", age: 67}); 
delete person.name`